# Method cannot be called from Class because of identifier

Tags: java

I am writing a java programming and trying to test it. Within the Class Card I have the format() statement telling it what to return. When I try to use this format on the newly created object, it throws the error that format() in card cannot be applied to (Card). I am not allowed to use a toString() statement as part of the assignment. Please help. Below is the class:

```
public class Card {
    private String name; 

    public Card() { 
        name = " "; 
    }

    public Card(String n) { 
        name = n; 
    } 

    public String getName() { 
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isExpired() { 
        return false;
    }

    public String format() { 
        return "Card holder: " + name; 
    } 
}
```

And here is the test file

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Lab12Test { 
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {   
        Card q = new Card("John");
        System.out.println("Card Class: ");
        System.out.println(Card.format(q) + "\n"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not really sure why you are doing `Card.format(q)`, but you should do this instead:

```
q.format()
```

`Card.format(q)` would work if `format` was a static method and took Card as an argument, which your method is not, it's an instance method.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am really new to programming and I had no clue about that. This worked!